# Deleting lines after fill in Illustrator CC

Tags: line-art

I'm new to Illustrator. always used flash for painting any vectors.

drawing a shape. A lightening bolt, with lines,they over lap at the ends.
how to delete the ends that hang over? and Or the whole line.

:) cheers

Comment: Hi John, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please give us a bit more information? A screenshot would help wonders clarifying your problem, and thus helps you getting a good answer. If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Hey there!!! thanks so much for your warm welcome. I figured it by turning the line work off currently, I'm sure this or another issue will show up in future so it's nice to have options!

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, consider posting the solution as an answer. That way, later visitors will have use of your Q and A--and that's what this site acatually is for!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if I understood your question but there is a nice thing that will help you in almost all your vector-related problems.

·Window> Pathfinder(Shift+ctrl+F9)

The pathfinder allows you to do several things to you vector figures, including the option Divide, which will divide all the different parts of your lighting bolt so you can manipulate them in separate ways. So, select your whole vector form and go to the Pathfinder panel and click Divide.

I suggest you get to know all of the pathfinder options because it's one of the most basic tools in Illustrator and it'll help a lot!